# EXE built with Visual Studio 2019 gives "DLL entry point" error, but lists EXE as DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to build a legacy project that builds and runs fine with VS 2010. I can provide any details necessary, but in a nutshell, this is an empty C++ project, with feeder-projects for C++ and Fortran that build static libraries and another that builds a GUI DLL.

I'm getting all of the individual projects to build individually just fine (or so it seems), but when I build and run the final EXE, I got an error message that read "The procedure entry point for _stop_core_quiet could not be located in the dynamic link library c:/user/projects/allinone2019/Debug/allinone2019.exe"

I thought the DLL name was supposed to be listed last, not the EXE name.

I've gone through the projects side-by-side in 2010 and 2019 and, except for the "$(VCInstallDir)" variables and such, all of my options are the same.

I remember when we upgraded to VS 2010 many years ago, we suddenly had to start copying 5 more DLLs to our BIN directory where our executables than we did with VS 2005. Do I need to be doing something like that here? If so, how do I find out what new DLLs I need?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Additional info: If my Fortran code has a STOP anywhere, even in a routine I don't call, I get the error. If I comment it out, it's fine. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why, but if I link using the libifcoremdd.lib library (multi-thread with debug) instead of libifcoremt.lib library (multithread) I get the DLL error. For my purposes, that's fine, and if I REALLY need to use STOP I can use "CALL EXIT(0)" instead.